# Overload Post RequestMapping

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am trying to overload the RequestMapping of a Spring controller. The Controller got POST as request Method and i need to pass it different params to overload it.

How could i do this, without changing the URL ?

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/windparks/import/error")
public ModelAndView handleFileUploadError(Locale locale, @AuthenticationPrincipal SpringUser authenticatedUser, List<RegulationEvent> regList, @RequestParam("regulations") MultipartFile regulations, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes, @PathVariable String windparkId) throws IOException, WindSpeedInterpolator.TimeSeriesMismatchException, SAXException {
    ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView("uis/windparks/parkdetail");

    view.addObject("failedEvents", regList);
    view.addObject("windparkId", windparkId);


    return view;
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/windparks/import/error")
public ModelAndView handleFileUploadError(Locale locale, @AuthenticationPrincipal SpringUser authenticatedUser, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes, @PathVariable String windparkId) throws IOException, WindSpeedInterpolator.TimeSeriesMismatchException, SAXException {
    ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView("uis/windparks/parkdetail");

    view.addObject("windparkId", windparkId);


    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `params` option in annotation `@RequestParam`, like this:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/windparks/import/error", params = {"locale", "authenticatedUser", "regList", "regulations", "windparkId"})
public ModelAndView handleFileUploadError(Locale locale, @AuthenticationPrincipal SpringUser authenticatedUser, List<RegulationEvent> regList, @RequestParam("regulations") MultipartFile regulations, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes, @PathVariable String windparkId) throws IOException, WindSpeedInterpolator.TimeSeriesMismatchException, SAXException {
    ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView("uis/windparks/parkdetail");

    view.addObject("failedEvents", regList);
    view.addObject("windparkId", windparkId);


    return view;
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/windparks/import/error", params = {"locale", "authenticatedUser", "windparkId"})
public ModelAndView handleFileUploadError(Locale locale, @AuthenticationPrincipal SpringUser authenticatedUser, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes, @PathVariable String windparkId) throws IOException, WindSpeedInterpolator.TimeSeriesMismatchException, SAXException {
    ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView("uis/windparks/parkdetail");

    view.addObject("windparkId", windparkId);


    return view;
}
```

Maybe not work for you, but you can check `params` manual in [Spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.3.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-params-and-headers).